# How to check text field via regex in Youtrack

Tags: regex, workflow, project-management, youtrack

How to check text field in youtrack with regexp in statemachine or stateless rule? I want to check that Review field contains link on upsource host, like: "assert Field.Regexp(regexp here)"

PS Or maybe I can do it with youtrack-upsource integration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keramblock, unfortunately it is not possible (neither via workflow nor via YT-UP integration).

However, you can probably solve your issue with `startsWith` or `contains` methods:

`assert Review.startsWith("http://upsource", opts): <message>;`

or

`assert Review.contains("upsource", opts): <message>;`